# ASP.NET 3.5 :No Postback triggered for button click

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, postback

I have an ASP.NET page developed in VS 2008. there is a text box and login button.Required fireld validator and Validtion Group controls are associate for validation.I wrote code for the Button click evenet handler too.But the Button click is not getting fired.There is no post back happening. Can any one tell me why ?

HTM lmarkup

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginPass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ValidationGroup="Login" ErrorMessage="Please enter password." runat="server" />


  <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"
              onclick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="Login" />
```

Comment: You can troubleshoot these types of problems by debugging the JavaScript code that runs in the button's `onclick` within the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Validators generate client side JavaScript which can prevent a postback if the required field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Is that exact code snippet? It didn't work at all - no such control as txtPassword.

Altough, this worked as expected:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ValidationGroup="Login" ErrorMessage="Please enter password." runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"
          onclick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="Login" />
```

I'm sure that you've got that correct in your code, so the problem must be somewhere else - could please post more code surrounding this snippet?

Comment: Yes i used the Wrong value in controlToValidate Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you have  `AutoPostBack="True"` on one of your components.  If so then remove that and your onclick should work on the button.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem. The RequiredFieldValidator was working as expected when the textbox was empty, but the button click wasn't causing a postback when there was text. My problem? I was using the same validationgroup name in a separate user control. So make sure all of your validationgroup names are unique.